# Magento doesnt work after set SSL

Tags: xml, magento, ssl

after i set SSL by panel admin in my Magento store, main content is blank with error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function asXml() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 324
```

but panel admin still works, i tried to find something about that, but i don't get any informations.

Anyone can help me?

Wrong lines:

```
if (Mage::app()->useCache('layout')) {
Mage::app()->saveCache($this->_packageLayout->asXml(), $cacheKey, $cacheTags, null);
}
```

Thanks, D

Comment: have you change the url in the database?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? I only have done changes in admin panel, I change URL to https, but only in admin panel.